# Designing Reports home page

Tags: homepage, reports

I need to design a home page to show around 20 reports with a bit of description of each report and a graph.
Currently I'm using  a springboard design (like thumbnails) where I see a snippet of each report along with a graph and to view the whole report I click on the button 'View Report'
But using this method, I end up with a lot of noise as there are too many charts shown on the screen and also there is too much scrolling.

Type of reports related to "Overall Summary", "Performance", "Activity", "ROI Tracking" etc.

Any inputs?

Thanks,
Roland

Comment: First give the information that what you have tried by yourself then ask. And you should mention that what kind of reports are there. For which area? Give some details.

Comment: Sure, have ellaborated on the question now

Answer (score 1):

As you have mention that in your page 20 reports are there so the best idea is to split your graph into similar category if possible. Like if report has category that consumer,Investors, Sales etc. Based on the category(s) make tab window in the same page so you don't need to jump on another page. After that arrange the graph based on most important first. I have given you some of the links below, that might be helpful to you.

The reason is,if you display 20 graph in the same screen that user might be confused that what are the important information to analyse first.

https://assets.econsultancy.com/images/0007/1785/23.jpg

https://dribbble.com/shots/1646404-Dashboard-data-charts/attachments/258171

https://dribbble.com/shots/368170-Dashboard-Full-2/attachments/18789

https://dribbble.com/shots/701798-Dashboard-Page-2-2/attachments/64684

https://dribbble.com/shots/1293039-MB-Widget/attachments/179656

https://in.pinterest.com/pin/289989663487159224/

https://dribbble.com/shots/739045-Kareer-me-Dashboard/attachments/71014

https://in.pinterest.com/pin/436497388862558344/

Comment: Thanks Jasmin, appreciate your help on this one. Would a dropdown for categories would be ideal of just tabs? Because by using tabs I feel that in future if the categories increase then might not have enough space horizontally.

Comment: If you find that in future more tabs will be there then make vertical tab window or drop down is also useful but I think 8-9 tabs will easily arranged horizontally at a time. And if in future you have tab greater than 10 then just divide whole report in main 2 category and then give tab menu suitable to the page.because it will be better to analyze.

Comment: Any link you can share as I haven't understood the main 2 category you are talking about. Thanks

Comment: i mean to say that if there are more than 10 types then if possible then divide all tabs in 2 parts for ex. Purchase and sales then include relevant tab in purchase and sales.

Comment: Hi Jasmin, thanks for that, appreciate it.
Now the requirement has slightly changed. The business wants to see all the reports at one go including a brief description on each. Any ideas rather then just displaying all together in the form of thumbnails? Thanks